# Standard for aligning data to week based on Mon to Sun for forecasting

Tags: time-series, dataset, forecasting

I need to produce a forecast where i have predicted volume to a standard definition of a week.

This definition is simply the week starts on Monday and Ends on Sunday.

Is there an ISO standard that already exists which communicates this?

Some more info:
We plan our business according to the Calendar year. So for example we plan out and allocate capacity from 1/1/xxxx to 12/31/xxxx. However I need to align sales data in the past. to do this requires consolidating it accurately so that past weeks can be used to predict future weeks. I'm hoping i can keep the forecasted week definition and past sales week definition the same for modeling input. weeknum=1, 2, 3 ... 52 etc.

I could pick a monday in the past and call all 7 days in that week "week 1". but wondering if there is already a standard which will do this and the assumptions/caveats around it commonly used? I see excel has a weeknum() function. Not sure if it uses a ISO standard etc.

Comment: see [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601).

Comment: There are standard tools for „day of week“, e.g. in Python, SQL, R. There are also „week of year“ functions. See here for Python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847213/how-do-i-get-the-day-of-week-given-a-date-in-python